# Why in my app Facebook's Chat Heads are not visible?

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, chat, visibility

I am creating an application for Android, but I've noticed that when someone sent me a message through facebook chat, chat bubbles (Chat Heads) are not visible. I have to leave my application to answer. And I do not want users to leave my application.

Why in my application, and only in certain activitys chat bubbles are not visible? 
What I can do to make them look at any activity?

Comment: How are those activities different from the others? any specific configuration changes etc?

Comment: @SMR No, for me is the same configuration. But for example, I implemented facebook login button, and when I'm in the logging Activity (provided by facebook) the Chat Heads are visible.

Comment: you aren't using fullscreen activities right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Chat Heads **does not overlay FULLSCREEN activities** (like games) in order to not bother users while they are doing supposed-to-be immersive actions (like playing).

Try to change your activity and be sure that it's not fullscreen or immersive.